# UIPage Control responding only after 4th page dot

Tags: uipagecontrol

Here is the code, when pages more than 5 the dots respond only after clicking on 4th page and above, while coming reverse the 2nd and 3rd dots are selectable

```
           if(self.eventDetailPages != Nil)
              [self.eventDetailPages removeFromSuperview]; 
            self.eventDetailPages = [[UIPageControl alloc] init];
            self.eventDetailPages.numberOfPages = self.evtListData.iTotalPages;
            NSLog(@"The total number of pages - %d", self.evtListData.iTotalPages);
            CGSize pageControlSize = [self.eventDetailPages sizeForNumberOfPages:self.eventDetailPages.numberOfPages];
            NSLog(@"The total width of pages - %f", pageControlSize.width);
            self.eventDetailPages.frame = CGRectMake(0, 150, pageControlSize.width,30);
            self.eventDetailPages.backgroundColor   = [UIColor blackColor];
            self.eventDetailPages.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, 150);
            self.eventDetailPages.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = TRUE;
            [self.eventDetailPages addTarget:self action:@selector(pageChanged:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            [self.view addSubview:self.eventDetailPages];
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, 4 dots are there, dots respond only on or after clicking on 3rd dot and above, while coming reverse the 2nd and 3rd dots are selectable
         [m_pPageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(gotonextPage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

```
   -(void)gotonextPage:(UIPageControl *) pageControl
     {   
      int page = m_pPageControl.currentPage;
       NSLog(@"PAGEVALUE%d",page);
      [m_pScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(page * m_pScrollView.frame.size.width,    0)animated:YES];

     }
```

What should I do? If I CLICK 2nd dot, the value of current page is not changing. if I click the 3rd then the value of current page is changing......